# Event Handler access context JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, binding, scope

I have a question in JavaScript context. I'm a little confused by this issue. The code below describes my question:

```
$(..).someFunction{
  var outOfScope = "OUT OF SCOPE!";

  $('somelink').click(handler);

  function handler() {
    alert(outOfScope);
  }
}
```

My question is: how outOfScope variable (which was defined outside the handler) is seen inside the handler?

Comment: See also Jibbering's [Javascript Closures](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) FAQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `outOfScope` is scoped to `someFunction`, so it is available *inside* `someFunction`.

The function `handler` is *inside* `someFunction`, so the variable `outOfScope` is still available.

Answer (score 0):

That´s how JavaScript works.

All variables that are defined directly inside a scope will also be available in all the scopes that are defined inside the scope.

Comment: Not quite true. Variables inside the scopes that are inside a scope are not available to the outer scope or other inner scopes. Just to be picky ;) Maybe you could put "directly inside a scope".